# Snowpark dataframe not returning with .collect() and will not allow looping through

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Basically what I'm trying to do is use the info schema to generate a dataframe of drop commands that I would then want to iterate through and execute.

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 

    drop_commands = session.sql(""" SELECT 'DROP ' || table_type ||  ' if exists <database>.' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ';' as drop_command
                                    FROM  <database>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                                    WHERE table_catalog = '<database>' 
                                        and table_schema in '<schema>'""").collect()
    
    for iter,row in df:
        session.sql(row['drop_command']).collect()

    # drop_commands.show()
    # Return value will appear in the Results tab.
    return drop_commands
```

I'm expecting that the drop_commands object will return as a data frame and then the loop will iterate through each drop command and drop snowflake object that I tell it to using the query.  When I comment out the loop and get rid of the .collect() at the end of the drop_commands definition then I can see the data frame returned in the results... However, this is contradictory to the documentation that Snowflake has available (* .collect() executes the sql *). I've tried different versions of the loop as well because of reading about the differences between a snowpark and pandas data frame to no avail.

Note that I would like to have these snowpark issues addressed regardless of whether there is an easier way to purge certain tables/schemas/databases - however if anyone does know how to do that programmatically that'd be great feedback as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm expecting that the drop_commands object will return as a data frame
>
> ```
> session.sql(""" """).collect()
> ```

First [snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.collect](https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/1.2.0/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.collect.html) returns `List[Row]`

Second it is perfectly possible to run `session.sql().collect()` inside a loop:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session):

    drop_commands = session.sql(""" SELECT 'DROP ' || REPLACE(table_type, 'BASE', '') ||  ' if exists TEST.' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ';' as drop_command
                                    FROM  TEST.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                                    WHERE table_catalog = 'TEST' 
                                        and table_schema in ('TEST')""").collect()
    
    for row in drop_commands:
        session.sql(row[0]).collect()

    return drop_commands
```

For env:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE TEST;
CREATE OR REPLACE SCHEMA TEST;


CREATE TABLE t1(i INT);
CREATE TABLE t2(i INT);

SHOW TABLES IN SCHEMA TEST.TEST;
-- T1
-- T2
```

Output:

[image]

```
SHOW TABLES IN SCHEMA TEST.TEST;
-- Query produced no results
```

And finally: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_TYPE` values are not only `VIEW/TABLE` so it cannot be concatenated with `DROP DML` without transfromation (BASE TABLE/EXTERNAL TABLE/VIEW/...).